# Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout after migration to androidx

Tags: android, androidx

I just made a migration to androidx through Android Studio menu option **Refactor** -> **Refactor to AndroidX**

I'm getting the following error:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout

Any idea?

Stacktrace:

```
2018-10-19 00:25:58.128 28131-28131/com.midounoo.midounoo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.midounoo.midounoo, PID: 28131
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.midounoo.midounoo/com.midounoo.midounoo.Base.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6255)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.midounoo.midounoo-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.midounoo.midounoo.Base.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6255)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
```

Comment: Show the whole stacktrace please.

Comment: Please share your app level build gradle so that we can see the dependencies.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

I solve my problem by changing all occurrences of

> **androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout**

to

> **androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout**

Comment: Yep, error in Android studio transformations, must change all occurence in xml layout with *androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout* ... thanks

Comment: I have created a new project with androidx support library and I already have androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout in my main activity but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Kanchan If you are working in a multi-module project, check if you need to update ConstraintLayout path in any.

Answer (score 51):

Add `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` to the dependencies:

```
dependencies  {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.constraintlayout/constraintlayout
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
}
```

It's available on `mavenCentral()`.

Comment: The second `constraintlayout` does not start by uppercase `C` however. Correct one: `'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'`

Comment: You saved me from a minor headache

Comment: I had to prioritize mavenCentral, very peculiar that my ide didn't already handle this for me.

Comment: Why does this happen on Android Studio? I changed it from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3. Thank you.

Comment: @BollMose - I don't know why, but 1.1.2 just chokes to death.  Probably some compatibility program that the nice people Google missed.  They tend to do that a lot; welcome to Android programming!

Comment: For me, this is should be the only acceptable answer. There's a bug consist of 1.1.2, the 1.1.3, fix this issue.

Comment: yep seems to be problem w/ 1.1.2. update to 1.1.3 fixed this for me too. thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, I resolved it as follows:

In your dependecies if you have added

`implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.x.x'` that is correct

but in your xml layout file you have to use the widget as

`androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 7):

build.gradle => check dependencies version

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.1'
```

to change

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

solved the problem

Comment: Its formatted fine and this answer worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: came from 1.1.2. updating to 1.1.3 fixed this for me too. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I has same issue after:

- migration support library to androidx;
- increment targetSdkVesrsion to 29;

I also use:

```
implementation "uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0"
```

I tried all posts from this question, but none success.

I fix it by adding one string `.disableCustomViewInflation()` to Calligraphy init:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    // ...
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Sans-Regular.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .disableCustomViewInflation() // <----- this fix
            .build());
    // ...
}
```

I hope next release of Calligraphy (Christopher Jenkins thanks for your great job) will fix it inside too.

Comment: I wasnt even using it in my project but the library was there in gradle. After removing it app started working as expected. Thanks

Comment: this one worked flawlessly for me. I'm on android studio 4 canary 15

Answer (score 5):

If after adding *mavenCentral()* as a repository in your Gradle file and changing `androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout` to `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` didn't solve your problem then try doing **Invalidate cache and restart** from the file menu. It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

make sure your project migrate to androidx completely , In my case I found :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

instead of

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

So change it and my problem fixed!

Answer (score 4):

After clicking on `Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX` , Make sure your all dependencies in the build.gradle(Module:app) is marked to the **newest version.**

If its not, dependency will appear in yellow highlighted color and you can change it by hovering the mouse over it.

Secondly,
Change the ConstraintLayout tag in all XML layout files to

> **androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout**

For more safer option, clean your project and sync it again after the above steps.

Answer (score 2):

Make Sure you have added the dependency for constraint layout

```
 dependencies  {
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
}
```

and have made the changes to

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout instead of

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted an existing ConstraintLayout tag from the xml, which was causing the issue for me. Simply deleting, and re-adding the ConstraintLayout tags in AndroidStudio from scratch fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to change to

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

instead of

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

**and**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
```

instead  of

```
<android.support.constraint.Barrier
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Android Studio 4.0. I used android studio 4.0 for a couple of days without problems. Seemingly out of nowhere the designer view stopped working.
I could only fix this by uninstalling android studio and installing the newest android studio version.

Answer (score 1):

Since my implementation was already `androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout`, just using a Clean Project solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

yepp. 
mavenCentral() and correct dependencies solve my same problems

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2757)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2818)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1557)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6393)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6858)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2710)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2818)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1557)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6393)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/constraintlayout/widget/R$styleable;
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.init(ConstraintLayout.java:590)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:567)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 25
```

Following the recomendations:

```
add androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout to the dependencies:

dependencies  {
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
}
```

And the repository  mavenCentral().

Works for me. I could compile the APK.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the dependency, yet it did not resolve the error.
Then I did a clean project and build and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find all default before to click Refactor -> Refactor to AndroidX
2. Open this https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings and find "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout". In same line  AndroidX class name is "androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout" copy it.

[image]

3. Replace all "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" to "androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout" in your project"s code, layout and menu. After all replace it will work.

**I mean find mapping and use it in whole project.**

Answer (score 0):

change your constraint layout dependancy to implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'

Answer (score 0):

None of the solution worked for me, looking closely at the exception stack trace:

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.XXX.XXX:drawable/walpaper" (7f0800aa)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0800aa a=-1 r=0x7f0800aa}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2690)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2614)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3791)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:524)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:520)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:516)
```

drawable background image loading was causing some issue on my old test device (newer devices load it just fine). Just removed the following line from my layouts it is working fine now, need to figure out how to set the background now..

```
 android:background="@drawable/walpaper"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with ImageFilterView **converting jpg images to png** solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was resolved by correctly setting the colors in the application. We carefully monitor the API version in each color used and simply change the color in case of a version higher than the minimum allowed. In the attributes, select Pick a Resource of the color that you want to check and pay attention here:
[check API version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxIFi.png)