# tried to access method com.google.common.io.Files.fileTreeTraverser() from class com.android.utils.FileUtils

Tags: android

I am getting below error after merge support library in androidx.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.io.Files.fileTreeTraverser()Lcom/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser; from class com.android.utils.FileUtils
    at com.android.utils.FileUtils.getAllFiles(FileUtils.java:394)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.StripDebugSymbolTransform.transform(StripDebugSymbolTransform.java:188)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 31 more
```

This problem is occurred after androidx merge. looks like that the problem seems to be in accessing the method Files.fileTreeTraverser() from class FileUtils.

Any ideas why its coming and how to fix it, please?

Comment: the issue with Gradle tool plugin, I updated gradle tool plugin(3.4.2) and android studio 3.4 latest version. issue resolved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I resolved issue by updating

- gradle build tool version

  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'`
- gradle wrapper properties file

  `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`
- Kotlin version to 1.3.10 or higher

  `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.10"`

Comment: @PhillipMwaniki what is your android studio version? are you using 3.4 or above version?

Comment: @SushilSolanki Android 3.5.2

Comment: @PhillipMwaniki Try with all above changes and cache clean