# After migrating to androidx: Didn't find class "androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, androidx, android-constraintlayout

I've searched for an answer to my problem, as shown in the title of this question, and found [Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout after migration to androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882606/error-inflating-class-androidx-constraintlayout-constraintlayout-after-migration), which aligns with the official migration instructions presented in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate). I took the information as requiring me to change `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`to `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`, but this doesn't work for me.

I haven't found anything about what dependency to put in my gradle file, so I tried this (this is a shot in the dark):

```
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

which is accepted but when I tried:

```
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout.widget:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

I get ***ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.constraintlayout.widget:constraintlayout:1.1.3***, so I used the previous implementation directive.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jbiss.petminder.activities.MainActivity">

<!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar-->
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:accessibilityLiveRegion="assertive"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
    tools:text="error message goes here"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvEmVet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/emergency_vet"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phoneCallEmVet"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerview1"
    tools:textSize="24sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/phoneCallEmVet"
    android:layout_width="37dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="callEmVet"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerview1"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_action_call"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="365dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/pet_name"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Running my app produces the following error:

```
2019-02-18 19:43:36.031 458-458/com.example.jbiss.petminder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jbiss.petminder, PID: 458
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.jbiss.petminder-i-ubC_oLu_y7-aFpiqALqg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.jbiss
```

Following the information doesn't work, for some reason. The migration has been tough but I've cleaned up a lot of issues and am now unable to find a reason why this is happening when it appears that I have done what is intended.

Comment: Are you confused between `build artifact name` and `class name` when migrating to AndroidX?

Comment: No, because I have no idea what either is. When I used Migrating to AndroidX, I found the Class Mappings table because it listed the classes that were being complained about in error messages, I now see that there is a table for Artifact Mappings. I do NOT understand what an artifact is or what to do with them as there is no information about it on that page. I will search for information as I assume that your question is a hint.

Comment: When I launched AS this morning, I am greeted with "Calculate task graph" errors, the blue ones are about ConstraintLayout, so I assume that there is some "artifact" issue. I have found and am reading a [The Reality of Migrating to AndroidX](https://blog.danlew.net/2018/11/14/the-reality-of-migrating-to-androidx/), so maybe I'll find something helpful.

Comment: From the little reading I've been able to do, it looks like "build artifacts" have to do with what is presented in the gradle file? For example, the Old is: android.arch.lifecycle:extensions and the "Androidx" is: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01, which I think means that I must make that change in my gradle file? This seems to be implied in **Migration Preparation** in  [The Reality of Migrating to AndroidX](https://blog.danlew.net/2018/11/14/the-reality-of-migrating-to-androidx/). Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 11):

I solved my problem. I found that Androidx migration is a bit more involved than I had at first thought. Knowing that I had updated the labels of the ConstraintLayout elements in the XML files used in the initial screen, I used Windows GREP to search for "**android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout**" throughout my project. Lo and behold I found instances that I had missed and so I updated the XML file reference to "**androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout**".

This allowed my project to be successfully built and launch on the emulator. However, after trying to access another screen I got the same error as shown in my initial post, but for the AppBarLayout. So, I must proceed for this one as I did for ConstraintLayout and then any others.

If you are migrating, be prepared for a little more work than you had anticipated!

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem after migrating to androidX. Tried above solution. But, it didn't work. I added mavenCentral() in project level app gradle.

```
 repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
            mavenCentral()
     }
```

with following changes

```
dependencies  {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
}
```

updated **"android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout"** xml tag with  **"androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout"**

finally it worked.

Comment: If you want people to upvote your solution, I recommend explaining at least how to add this repository.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. Android Studio suggested to replace the jcenter() line to mavenCentral() so I think that line is not needed. It is working without it for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you experience this issue on Android Studio 3.6.3 after using the Migrate to Androidx tool like I did, Here is what worked for me:

I was using `androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout` in my layout XML file instead of `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`

The difference is one has widget before ConstraintLayout. The dependency in my app-level build.gradle was:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

The latest at that time.