# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android

I am trying to learn the android development by my self as I was trying to make a simple text changing app using a button and a text view but while running it on my own mobile using USB it started showing, unfortunately, the app has stopped. if you don't mind in helping me to understand y this error is coming and how to resolve it.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 package com.nanb.wishes;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
TextView txt1, txt2;
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    final TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            txt1.setText("Happy birthday to a special person who is bringing so much joy with her smile. I am thankful for every moment we spend together, and I wish your happiness never ends.");
            txt2.setText("");
        }
    });

    btn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            txt1.setText(" May this day be as sunny as your smile, and as beautiful as you are. You shine every day, but on this day you will shine the brightest. Happy Birthday");
            txt2.setText("");
            return true;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/birthday"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="328dp"
    android:layout_height="113dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="203dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="61dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="464dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
    android:text="@string/welcome"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt2"
    android:layout_width="325dp"
    android:layout_height="107dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="61dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="332dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
    android:text="@string/step"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="142dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="168dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="201dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Click Here"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt2" />
```

logcat

```
 08-02 15:34:04.717 31123-31123/com.nanb.wishes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nanb.wishes, PID: 31123
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nanb.wishes/com.nanb.wishes.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.nanb.wishes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.nanb.wishes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.nanb.wishes:drawable/birthday" (7f070055)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070055 a=-1 r=0x7f070055}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2456)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2396)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3748)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:498)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:494)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:490)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:575)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.nanb.wishes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288) 
    at `enter code here`android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
 08-02 15:39:05.031 31123-31123/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31123 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Make sure you have added `dependencies` of `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'`

Comment: Error occurring in `ConstraintLayout`, so check this link it may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882606/error-inflating-class-androidx-constraintlayout-constraintlayout-after-migration/52882787

Comment: What type of file is the `birthday` drawable, and exactly which folder(s) is it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some errors which will come after the migration android project to androidX project.

Here is some step to check or solve those errors

**Step 1 :-** Make Sure about your implementation in gradle file.

**Step 2 :-** Android studio automatically change all libraries implementation and it's uses according to android X. if somehow not done then change in .xml file

Example :-

```
     androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout (wrong).
```

change to

```
     androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout (right).
```

**Note:-** You have to add

```
     android.enableJetifier=true
     android.useAndroidX=true
```

this two-line in gradle.properties file. If the file doesn't exist then create it.
While you are migrating your Project.

**Now, This is almost Done**

If after that also Error comes then please build > Rebuild. **or** You can choose Invalidate caches / Restart from file menu.

I think it will work and helpfull to all who are migrating their project.