# Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView after migration to androidx

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview, androidx

I just made a migration to androidx through Android Studio menu option Refactor -> Refactor to AndroidX

I'm getting the following error:

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Any idea?

Stacktrace:

```
10-28 20:01:59.913 13394-13394/com.example.impwala E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.impwala, PID: 13394
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.impwala/com.example.impwala.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5133)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.impwala.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5133) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.impwala.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5133) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:856)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2129)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3685)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:651)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:647)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.impwala.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5133) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I already tried answers from this question but they didn't help me

[Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout after migration to androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882606/error-inflating-class-androidx-constraintlayout-constraintlayout-after-migration)

Comment: Make sure that after migrating your build.gradle file contains "implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'" this dependency.

Comment: OutOfMemoryError on Resources.loadDrawable. Which kind of drawable are you using?

Comment: I am using a jpg file and also a XML file for gradient n my drawable folder.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

First in the XML file make sure you have this signature

```
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

**if you do have it**

open the logcat
and read the whole error. You might see caused by .. and this is your actual error
for me it was `@dimen/somedimen`. I wrote  the value 10, so when I fix it 10dp. my problem solved.

Comment: This is unbelievable. I had the exact same mistake. I wrote without "dp". That shows me what big impact such small changes have

Answer (score 0):

I changed the signature in the XML to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView and It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `RecyclerView:1.3.0` and when I set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` this error appear. Also in this case, the preview of recyclerview in Android Studio doesn't work. So to get ride of this error I set `android:animateLayoutChanges="false"`.