# My Android App is crashing when downloaded from the Playstore but when I run it from Android Studio into any device it works normally

Tags: java, android, kotlin, androidx

During development I changed the android dependencies from android to androidx

If I install the app from Android Studio to any device the app work just fine, but when I download the same version of the app from the playstore it crashes on the First Activity OnCreate method when setting the content layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_up)
```

This is the error but I don't know what to do to Fix it

```
Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout**
```

These are the logs

```
**Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout**
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at co.devpenguin.dts.StartUpActivity.onCreate(StartUpActivity.kt:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/constraintlayout/widget/R$styleable;
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.init(ConstraintLayout.java:590)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:567)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at co.devpenguin.dts.StartUpActivity.onCreate(StartUpActivity.kt:23) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/co.devpenguin.dts-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.devpenguin.dts-2/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.devpenguin.dts-2/split_config.hdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/co.devpenguin.dts-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.init(ConstraintLayout.java:590) 
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:567) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at co.devpenguin.dts.StartUpActivity.onCreate(StartUpActivity.kt:23) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Comment: You try this? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882606/error-inflating-class-androidx-constraintlayout-constraintlayout-after-migration/52882787

Comment: Yes, thanks that solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to upgrade the constraintLayout library as posted here

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882606/error-inflating-class-androidx-constraintlayout-constraintlayout-after-migration/52882787)

I change the version from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```